# Create filled shape with \foreach

Tags: foreach

I now did it manually, but I'm interested in how I can do this with a loop:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{Punkt} = [coordinate]

\node[Punkt] (Center) at (0, 0) {};
\draw[-, thick, fill=black!30!white]{[rounded corners=1.5pt] ([shift={(30:1.2)}]Center)  arc (30:34:1.2) -- 
                                             ([shift={(36:1.5)}]Center)  arc (36:84:1.5) --  
                                             ([shift={(86:1.2)}]Center)  arc (86:94:1.2) --
                                             ([shift={(96:1.5)}]Center)  arc (96:144:1.5) --
                                             ([shift={(146:1.2)}]Center)  arc (146:154:1.2) --
                                             ([shift={(156:1.5)}]Center)  arc (156:204:1.5) --
                                             ([shift={(206:1.2)}]Center)  arc (206:214:1.2) --
                                             ([shift={(216:1.5)}]Center)  arc (216:264:1.5) --
                                             ([shift={(266:1.2)}]Center)  arc (266:274:1.2) --
                                             ([shift={(276:1.5)}]Center)  arc (276:324:1.5) --
                                             ([shift={(326:1.2)}]Center)  arc (326:334:1.2) --
                                             ([shift={(336:1.5)}]Center)  arc (336:384:1.5) --
                                             ([shift={(386:1.2)}]Center)  arc (386:390:1.2)                                     
                                            };
\draw [fill=white, opacity=1, thick] (Center) circle [radius=1];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pic1]

If I try something like this:

```
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}{ 
\draw[-, fill=green][rotate=(\i-1)*360/6] 
{[rounded corners=1.5pt] ([shift={(29:1.2)}]Center)  arc (29:34:1.2) -- 
([shift={(36:1.5)}]Center)  arc (36:84:1.5) --  
([shift={(86:1.2)}]Center)  arc (86:91:1.2);
}
```

It is only filled between the start- and end-point of each segment:

[image: pic2]

Thank you for help.
Konne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the `\foreach` inside the `\draw`.  This makes it a single path and thus fully fillable.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{Punkt} = [coordinate]

\node[Punkt] (Center) at (0, 0) {};

\draw[-, fill=green]  ([shift={(29:1.2)}]Center)
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,6}{ 
  [rotate=(\i-1)*360/6]
  {[rounded corners=1.5pt]  arc (29:34:1.2)    -- 
([shift={(36:1.5)}]Center)  arc (36:84:1.5) --  
([shift={(86:1.2)}]Center)  arc (86:91:1.2) --   ([shift={(89:1.2)}]Center)
}
};

\draw [fill=white, opacity=1, thick] (Center) circle [radius=1];


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```